# How do I populate a C# ComboBox with the names of the last 4 months?

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I want to display the names of the last 4 months in a ComboBox using C#. When a user selects a month  I need to pass the date/time to a query. How can I display the month name while using a date/time as the value?

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: How are you determining the date time based on just the month value?

Answer (score 2):

Bind your combo box by `DisplayMember = 'Month Name'` and `ValueMember = theDateTime`

```
ListItemCollection items = new ListItemCollection();
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
for (int count = 1; count <= 4; count++)
{
    items.Add(new ListItem(now.ToString("MMM"), now.ToString()));
    now.AddMonths(-1);
}
combobox.DisplayMember = "Text";
combobox1.ValueMember = "Value";
combobox1.DataSource = items;
```

Then get the user selected value in date time

```
DateTime selected = Convert.ToDateTime(combobox1.SelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't give much in terms of details.  I assume selected month value is an integer.  You can create a dummy DateTime object to have as a placeholder for your month value:

```
new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, selectedMonth, DateTime.Now.Day);
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just another idea: the solution below stores the real DateTime in the List instead of just the month, e.g., 5/1/2011.  When the combo box is selected, the output will really be the date.

Code behind:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyMonths = new List<DateTime>();
        var thisMonth = new DateTime(
            DateTime.Now.Year,
            DateTime.Now.Month,
            1);

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            MyMonths.Add(thisMonth.AddMonths(-i));
        }

        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public List<DateTime> MyMonths
    {
        get { return (List<DateTime>)GetValue(MyMonthsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyMonthsProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyMonthsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyMonths", typeof(List<DateTime>), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
```

Xaml:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox x:Name="dateCombo" 
                  Margin="10"
                  SelectedIndex="0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MyMonths}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource dateTimeConverter}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

DateTimeConverter:

```
public class DateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is DateTime)
        {
            var d = (DateTime)value;
            return d.ToString("MMM");
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**Update:** For formatting the month:

```
String.Format("{0:M MM MMM MMMM}", dt);  // "3 03 Mar March"  month
```